# не могу подключить simpleblog к django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь подключить приложение, но выдаёт ошибку:

> Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an
>   explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Посмотрел интернеты, находил похожие проблемы, но решения не помогли. Может кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой при подключении данного приложения и знает как её решить?

Comment: Добавить `django.contrib.sites` в `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @andreymal Добавлял, но дальше вылетает вот это: You're using the Django "sites framework" without having set the SITE_ID setting. Create a site in your database and set the SITE_ID setting or pass a request to Site.objects.get_current() to fix this error. Не понимаю что с этим делать. Наверно стоило с этого вопрос начать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `INSTALLED_APPS` должен быть `django.contrib.sites`. После чего, в настройках надо указать `SITE_ID`, это может быть существующий ID или же с использованием `Site.objects.get_current()`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    ...
]

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
SITE_ID = Site.objects.get_current()
```

**ИЛИ**

Вы можете добавить [миддлвар](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware), что тоже должно решить вашу проблему:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware',
]
```